# Qt - connect signals of dynamical created widgets

Tags: qt, signals-slots

I have a list of functions with parameters. For each parameter I create a spinbox holding its value. Some functions have zero parameters others have n>1 parameters.

The code looks like this (simplified)

```
for (int i = 0; i < parameterList.size(); ++i) {

    QString valueName = parameterList().at(i);
    double value = parameter(valueName);

    QDoubleSpinBox * spinbox = new QDoubleSpinBox();
    QLabel * label = new QLabel();
    label->setText(valueName);
    spinbox->setValue(value);

    // does NOT work, Slot need three parameters!
    QObject::connect(spinbox, &QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged,
                        this,  &OnAmplitudeParameterChanged);

    ... add widgets to layout
}
```

However the slot needs to know which widgets was calling, the parameter name and its value. The signal however provides only a value.

The slot looks like this

```
OnAmplitudeParameterChanged(int index, QString name, double value)
```

How is this solved in Qt? I found a QSignalMapper class but not how this would solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on Wiki Wang's answer, use the combination of `sender()`, `qobject_cast` and the spinbox's object name:

In your code:

```
QString valueName = parameterList().at(i);
double value = parameter(valueName);

QDoubleSpinBox * spinbox = new QDoubleSpinBox();
spinbox->setObjectName(valueName);
```

Then in the slot:

```
void SomeClass::OnAmplitudeParameterChanged(double value)
{
    QDoubleSpinBox *spinbox = qobject_cast<QDoubleSpinBox *>(sender());
    if (spinbox && parameterList.contains(spinbox->objectName()) {
        int value = parameter(spinbox->objectName());
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: It does not compile `QDoubleSpinBox *spinbox = qobject_cast<QDoubleSpinBox>(QObject::sender());` gives me the error ` error: cannot convert 'QDoubleSpinBox' to 'QDoubleSpinBox*' in initialization`

Comment: @MatthiasPospiech Whoops. That should be `<QDoubleSpinBox *>`. I have fixed the answer, as well.

Answer (score 3):

I would use a little lambda for that

```
auto func = [i, valueName, this](double value){
    OnAmplitudeParameterChanged(i, valueName, value);
};

QObject::connect(spinbox, &QDoubleSpinBox::valueChanged, func);
```

**EDIT**

Jon Harper's answer inspired me to use the `QObject::setProperty()` as another interesting solution:

```
QDoubleSpinBox* spinbox = new QDoubleSpinBox();
spinbox->setProperty("myindex", i);
spinbox->setProperty("myname", valueName);
```

and then in your slot:

```
void SomeClass::OnAmplitudeParameterChanged(double value)
{    
    int index = sender()->property("myindex").toInt();
    QString name = sender()->property("myname").toString();
}
```

But still, I would probably use the lambda anyway.

Comment: Can you provide a more detailed example with the lambda? The func is only available within the function which defines the connect. Also the parameters are only known there. I do not understand thus how this should work.

Comment: @Matthias The `func` is a **function object** created with the help of lambda expression. It has all necessary parameters stored inside (those within the **lambda capture-list**) and the `connect()` method makes a copy of it for later invocation. I hope it makes a sense to you.

Comment: Just a note: instead of `auto func = ...` it could be also `std::function<void()> func = ...`

Comment: No really, even if the lambda is copied, when connect is executed `valueName' is not available.

Comment: So, when the lambda is created the `valueName` variable contains correct value, but when the lambda is executed, the `valueName` inside lambda body is empty? That would be a little strange behavior. How about index `i`? And is your lambda capture list same as I have suggested?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [QObject::sender()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#sender) to get the caller spinbox in the slot function.

```
QDoubleSpinBox *spinbox = static_cast<QDoubleSpinBox *>(QObject::sender());
```

Comment: Note: `qobject_cast` is safer and preferred.